# Spring DMLC message consumption: auto_ack vs Transacted Session

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-integration

I have couple of questions regarding spring DMLC.

1. Why it is recommended by spring vendors to use DMLC(Default Message Listener Container) with transactions?

[Spring DLMC and JMSTemplate behavior while using Transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266881/spring-dlmc-and-jmstemplate-behavior-while-using-transactions)

2. On consumer side if I use DMLC with sessionTransacted=false, it will use ACTO_ACK mode by default. What is the difference between both the cases (Transactions and AUTO_ACK) ? 
   According to my understanding, Acknowledgement process looks similar to me in both the cases:

**Transacted**: As soon as message is received by the consumer, a commit will be send to broker and thn only broker will consider message as delivered.

**Auto_Ack**: Here also for each message received by the consumer, a acknowledgement will be send to the broker by consumer.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks,

Anuj

Answer (score 1):

With the DMLC and auto ack, the message is acked as soon as it is received (and **before** the listener is called).

With **transacted**, the session is committed **after** the listener is called; and, if the listener throws an exception (or the system loses power), the transaction is rolled back (message requeued).

Comment: Thanks Gary. Which means performance wise AUTO_ACK is better than transactions?                                                       and Why it is recommended by spring vendors to use DMLC(Default Message Listener Container) with transactions?

Comment: It entirely depends on your requirements; if you don't care about losing messages then, yes, it will be slightly faster. If you care about losing messages, you need transactions. Consider using the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` instead of `DMLC` if you don't need transactions.